# Удаление участником всех своих вопросов и ответов

Tags: обсуждение, удаление-вопросов, удаление-ответов

Представим, что участник ruSO "нашел причину" и удалил все свои вопросы и ответы, которых допустим - тысячи. Что конкретно происходит в таком случае? Удаленное бесследно исчезнет? Сообщество среагирует или смирится с таким "ущербом"?

Comment: не так-то просто удалить вопросы и ответы

Comment: Видите в футере сайта слова "пользовательский контент попадает под действие лицензии cc by-sa 3.0"?

Comment: Тут, можно так сказать -- "вход рубль, выход два". Так что хорошенько подумайте, чем вы хотите делиться.

Comment: Удалить вопрос, если для него уже есть заплюсованные ответы, вроде бы и вовсе не получится самостоятельно.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Как написал A K](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4552/%d0%a3%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2#comment15857_4552), по умолчанию все вопросы/ответы публикуются с лицензией [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/deed.en).
Поэтому все ответы и вопросы могут быть восстановлены.

Более того, если эти вопросы/ответы представляют ценность для сообщества, они *будут* восстановлены, действия юзера будут расценены как вандализм, юзер будет забанен.

Comment: а можно пункт из лицензии про _все ответы и вопросы могут быть восстановлены._?

Comment: @Grundy, да хоть так: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/587303/178988 => http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/587822/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy, :-) не, то, что можно скопировать и вставить - это я видел :-) я хотел узнать где об этом в лицензии что-то написано :)

Comment: @Grundy, это есть в ToS: You grant Stack Exchange the perpetual and irrevocable right and license to use, copy, cache, publish, display, distribute, modify, create derivative works and store such Subscriber Content and, except as otherwise set forth herein, to allow others to do so in any medium now known or hereinafter developed (“Content License”) in order to provide the Services, **even if such Subscriber Content has been contributed and subsequently removed by You**.

Comment: @Nofate, но это относится к тому, что _все вопросы/ответы публикуются с лицензией_? или это просто соглашение? кстати, как ToS разворачивается? :-)

Comment: @Grundy Terms of Service. Про лицензию - предложение перед тем, которое я запостил: You agree that all Subscriber Content that You contribute to the Network is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Exchange under the Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike license.